Is there an analog for factorials in division, and if so, what are its applications and properties?
If we consider a factorial to be an operation/function of iterative multiplication, would it be reasonable to think that something similar for division also exists?
If we take this function to be f, the idea I have is as follows:
We first compute $\frac{5}{4} = 1.25$ . After this, we further divide this by 3
$\frac{1.25}{3} \approx 0.4167$
Then b $\frac{0.4167}{2} \approx 0.20834$
This process goes on until we hit 1.
After brainstorming, I realised all I was doing was repeatedly multiplying by the reciprocal of the next number in the list, or $5 \cdot \left(\frac{1}{4} \right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{3} \right) \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) \cdot (1)$
And so, by observation I generalised this result to $f(n) = \frac{n}{{(n-1)}!}$
And upon further algebra we get
\begin{equation}
f(n)=\frac{n^2}{n!}
\end{equation}
Where could such an operation be useful, and why hasn't such a thought been given attention? What would the properties of this function look like? (Derivatives, Integrals, Convergence etc)

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

I don't know that there's a specific term for that. I usually see it represented as ratios of double factorials.

Incidentally, your handwritten expression is totally ambiguous. Division is a binary operation that isn't associative, so you'll need to use parentheses or the like to group it.

@BrianTung So how do we go about thinking about a function like this?

$f (5)= \frac{5}{4}/\frac{3}{2}/1$ still requires more explanation. Where do the brackets go?
$\frac{7}{6}/(\frac{5}{4}/(\frac{3}{2}/1))$ or $((\frac{7}{6}/\frac{5}{4})/\frac{3}{2})/1$

I view factorials as a way to multiply continuously, so the question of dividing continuously popped into my mind.

I suggest you give values of $f(\cdot)$ for a few small numbers, so we know what you're thinking of. As it stands, it's still ambiguous. We can't answer the question of how to think about the function without knowing what the function is.

Please edit your post for clarity. As others have pointed out, division is not associative so writing things like $a/b/c$ is not meaningful.  You need to explain the order of operations you intend.

One thought:  factorials are easily defined recursively, using $n!=n\times (n-1)!$.  Perhaps you have a recursive definition in mind for your "iterated divisions"?  If so, it would be useful if you included that in your post.

@lulu Yes this is precisely what I have in mind. I will add this to my post

One interpretation of your written note might be: $5/(4/(3/(2/(1))))=15/8$ ?

If you could clarify that your divisions are left to right, then that would be helpful and the $f(5) = 5/4/3/2/1 = \cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac{\cfrac54}3}2}{1}$ is at least defined.

For instance, calling your operation $@$, do you mean $1@=1$ and $n@=(n-1)@/n$?   I think that's a consistent definition...not sure if it is what you intend, though.

Maybe something like $f(x+1) = x/f(x)$?

To be sure:  my recursive definition just comes down to $\frac 1{n!}$

@pshmath0: If so, that is what double factorials are sometimes used for. They show up in certain integrals. I'm sure someone else can be more specific.

Multiplication is associative, and also commutative. For your example of $5!$, it may be similarly interpreted as one of the $120$ ways to permute the factors with $14$ ways to apply binary multiplication. Replacing multiplication by division, and then your new $f$ has to be carefully defined.

Voting to close the question for lack of clarity.  Please don't make your readers guess what you intend.  If possible, please edit your post to explain what it is you want to compute.

@lulu I have explained my school of thought in the comments to Brian's answer

As some of us have indicated in the comments to the OP, repeated division without grouping is ambiguous because division is not associative. That is,
$$
(a \div b) \div c \not= a \div (b \div c)
$$
Therefore, when doing multiple consecutive divisions, grouping needs to be indicated. While we're waiting for OP to be clearer, I will simply point out that left associativity and right associativity give results that typically do not need new notation. For example, right associativity gives
\begin{align}
f(n) & \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \frac{n}{f(n-1)} \\
     & = \frac{n}{n-1}f(n-2) \\
     & = \frac{n}{n-1}\cdot\frac{n-2}{f(n-3)} \\
     & \phantom{=} \vdots \\
     & = \frac{n!!}{(n-1)!!}
\end{align}
where $n!!$ is the double factorial. Left associativity gives the even simpler
\begin{align}
f(n) & \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} n \prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k} \\
     & = \frac{n}{(n-1)!}
\end{align}

After much brainstorming and trial and error, I have come to the result that  Brian has, in a different way. For example, to compute f(5) I was taking 5/4, and further dividing that by 3, taking that new value and further dividing it by 2. I realised that this iterated division could be thought of as an iterated multiplication of the reciprocals, and arrived at the same expression that they did. Thank you everyone for your insights and advice !

@PratixitTripathy: You should still edit your question to improve its clarity for future readers.

@BrianTung Why did you answer the question , if you admit it is still unclear.

@BrianTung noted, thank you for your answer

@Peter: Because I think the expression template has two "natural" interpretations, and I think showing the OP (and others) how to represent that and determine a closed (-ish) form is useful to the OP (in all likelihood) and the site generally. I understand that many users of the site don't agree. I think they cleave a little too strictly to a slightly counter-productive policy, but it's a point of reasonable disagreement and for the most part I don't stress out about it.

@PratixitTripathy: It would really help avoid down-votes on your question and my answer if you would add the context that many of us have requested.
